# bitwise OR on logical vector(s) stored in list

Tags: r

Is there more concise/efficient/easier way of doing this? Method below is considered bad practice. Note, that the method should work on input with an arbitrary N logical vectors.

```
z = m[[1]]
lapply(2:length(m), function(i) z<<-z|m[[i]])
```

## Input

```
$V1
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[31] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[46] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

$V2
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[31] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[46] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

## Output

```
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[31] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[46] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

## Data

```
m = structure(list(V1 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE), V2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)))
```

Comment: Your anonymous function takes in x but uses z, m, and i - this is a problem.  You might also want to explain what exactly you're trying to do.  If the code doesn't do what you want then just giving us the code isn't going to be as helpful as explaining what you want to do.

Comment: Fixed it, should say `function(i)` The code does what I need; it is just bad code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "or" all the vectors in `m`, a simple way is

```
Reduce(`|`, m)
```

This is your desired output

```
desired <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

and we see that

```
all(Reduce(`|`, m)==desired)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

When I think of extending logical OR I think of the function `any`.  Basically what we want to do is pass in each of the vectors into your list into `any` piecewise.  This sounds like a job for `mapply`.  We need to do some manipulation to get things in the form that it all works though.  The following should do and doesn't care how many vectors are in 'm'.

```
do.call(mapply, c("any", m))
```

Comment: How would you translate your code `do.call(what = mapply, args = c("any", m))` into `mapply(any, ...)` form?

Comment: `mapply(any, m[[1]], m[[2]], m[[3]])` and so on.  The issue is that if you don't know how many vectors are in m this would be tedious.  That's the reason I use `do.call` so that the vectors themselves are passed in as different elements to the call to `mapply`.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding how `args=c("any", m))` can essentially expand to `mapply(FUN = any, m[[1]], m[[2]]...m[[n]])` and it is not `mapply(FUN = any, ...=m)`.

Comment: @Vlo c("any", m) will return a list with "any" as the first element and then the elements of m as the 2nd through (n+1)th elements.  These elements will be passed along positionally so that the first element in our list of arguments will be the first positional argument in mapply (which happens to be fun FUN) and then the second element in our list (m[[1]]) will be the second positional element to mapply (which happens to be ...) and since that second element is ... all of the other values that aren't explicitly a named parameter will get passed along into ... which ends up giving what I said.

Comment: @Vlo How familiar are you with the `...` parameter in R?